# data frame error in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I try to subset two columns ("nitrates" and "sulfate") from many files that have typical numbers of rows and columns. here is my code ..

```
   pollutant <- if(pollutant == TRUE){
      id[,"nitrate"]
      } else {
           id[,"sulfate"]
             }
```

I should use these columns to count the meaning of these columns.
please give me a hand, I am a new comer to R

Comment: Question is not clear, what is the input and expected output?

Comment: the arguments are (data, pollutant, id )

Comment: How your data looks like?

Comment: pollutantmean <- function(specdata, pollutant, id = 1:332){
        specdata <- setwd("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/coursera/specdata")
        id <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
                for(i in 1:length(id)){
                        assign(id[i], read.csv(id[i]))
                }
        pollutant <- if(pollutant == TRUE){
                       id[,"nitrate"]
                        } else {
                      id[,"sulfate"]
                                }
        mean(pollutant, na.rm = FALSE)
}

Comment: It seems you are storing multiple dataframes in a list called `id`. If so, using `id[, "nitrate"]` won't access a dataframe, but will look for an object called `nitrate` within the list. Try `id[[i]][, "nitrate"]`.

Comment: @LAP .. It gives me the same error.. 
> pollutantmean("specdata", "pollutant", 1)
Error in id[[i]][, "sulfate"] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Please provide a data example. Use `dput()` on one of your dataframes (or, if too big, use `dput(head())` and paste the output into your question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `if` only accept single values each times. In case `pollutant` is a `data.frame` structure or similar, the `if` loop is going fail. My suggestion is try to use the `data.table` environment. It makes life much more easier for what it seems you want to do (I don't completely get it from your text).

```
    library(data.table)

    pollutant <- data.table(pollutant)
    Pollutat.Subset <- pollutant[id == "nitrate" | id =="sulfate",]
```

This should subset your data based on the identity of ID.

Comment: Here is my whole code ..
pollutantmean <- function(specdata, pollutant, id){
        specdata <- setwd("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/coursera/specdata")
        id <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
        for(i in seq_along(id)){
                assign(id[i], read.csv(id[i]))
        }
        pollutant <-  id[c("nitrate","sulfate")]
    
        mean(complete.cases(pollutant), na.rm = TRUE)
}
and i want to count the mean of the "nitrate" and "sulfate" in every file I call

Comment: The out put is >  Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 332, 1461 and I don't know what to do !!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your code because you send me a reference to a file in your laptop. You have to generate some random data which resembles to yours so I can reproduce the error in my computer. In addition, from your question is still not completely clear what you want. If what you need is the mean by group, use the `data.table` or `dplyr` packages. Makes life easier.